# Flutter Firebase auth too many requests

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I was building an email verification page on my flutter app for users to verify their emails before they can sign in. So in the verification page, I have a button that allows the users to resend the verfication email after 5 seconds from the time they sent.

```
  Future sendVerificationEmail() async {
    try{
      final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
      await user.sendEmailVerification();

      setState(() => canResendEmail = false);
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
      canResendEmail = true;

    }catch (e) {
      Utils.showSnackBar(e.toString());
    }
  }

...............................

ElevatedButton.icon(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.email, size: 32),
            label: const Text("Resend email"
            ),
            onPressed: canResendEmail ? sendVerificationEmail : null,
        ),
```

But then the problem is when I try to resend the email again, most of the time i get the error which says:

> [firebase-auth/too many requests] We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later.

Well, I understand that this is great for security but its just not consistent at all. Like sometimes I can resend 5 emails within 30 seconds and sometimes it will keep showing this error for more than 2 minuetes.
My question is whether i can set some rules in the firebase to make that I can like send certain number of email requests per seconds or like at least get to know what is the exact time that I need to wait before I can send a request again instead of this random situation where sometimes I can send multiple requests within short time.

Comment: Firebase allows 1000 requests / day but does not mention a time frame or cooldown period. However, I would simply go with 60 seconds as this is pretty normal. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#email_limits

Comment: @Dabbel Thanks, I think ya I will go with 60 second’s, it seems normal and convenient

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get past this by setting a provided option to disable the verification check during testing activities ([see documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthSettings#setAppVerificationDisabledForTesting(boolean))). It looks like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.setSettings(appVerificationDisabledForTesting: true);
```